# Making a damage system with random numbers

Tags: java, string, random, system, subtraction

I am trying to make a project for school, and I want to really make this stand out from the others by doing something I have never done before.

I want to make a system that will subtract random numbers from 100 or 1000 from your own health and from your opponents health, depending on who's turn it is.
This is a simple pop-up game so it doesn't have to be too complicated with a healthbar etc.
Bear in mind that the numbers are in Strings, not int.

I have looked everywhere for some kind of guide which does this, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Not really clear what you want.. Where are you stuck exactly? Have you tried anything?

Comment: have you tried outsourcing it?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I want exactly what I stated.
A method that will subtract random numbers from 100 or 1000 from either your own health, or your opponents health. The numbers are in strings.

Comment: @SandraVernon no one will do your homework for you. You must try first and in the process if you are stuck somewhere and if you cannot solve then you can come here, people will help. But people won't write code for you.

Comment: If I hadn't tried, do you really think I would ask someone on the internet rather than people working with me?

Comment: Not a Real Question: If there is some code that just doesn't work as expected, post that, along with a description of how it doesn't work. There is not enough context.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random();

getCurrentPlayer().modifyHealth(-rand.nextInt(901) + 100);
```

No more help to give here I'm afraid, since you didn't paste any code or additional details.